# Java 1.6 in Mac does not have SwingWorker

Tags: java, macos, swingworker

I'm having problems migrating my Java files from Ubuntu to Mac. Mac complains about my use of SwingWorker---it can't find javax.swing.SwingWorker .

In Mac's terminal, doing `java -version` tells me I have version 1.6.0_03-p3. In Ubuntu, I have 1.6.0_20. Is it that big a difference? How do I upgrade Mac's Java so I can use SwingWorker?

Thanks!

## EDIT:

I followed the link at TofuBeer's reply. My eclipse.ini now reads as

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

I've restarted Eclipse but it still does not recognize SwingWorker. Is there anything wrong with my eclipse.ini? I tried to navigate to the path indicated under -vm. I noticed that in Versions, the folder for 1.6.0 is just a shortcut (not an actual directory). Will that affect anything?

(Barring the fact that the folder 1.6.0 in Versions is just a shortcut, the path indicated *does* exist.)

Comment: What version of OSX do you have and what hardware platform?

Comment: @TofuBeer OSX 10.5.8, Intel Core 2 Duo

Comment: for SwingWorker is required Java 6_022 and higher, fixes some critical bugs

Answer (score 1):

It does!

[image: evidence]

At least on v1.6.0_26, probably wasn't there on  1.6.0_03-p3 try updating your Java version, should be as simple as running Software update:

[image: software update]

Comment: That gave me an idea. I tried to compile it via command line. It compiled well. But when I ran it, it said that SwingWorker cannot be resolved to a type. It also complained about SwingWorker-related methods like `setProgress` and `addPropertyChangeListener`. And then, running Software Update only three programs are listed: Remote Desktop Client, Migration Assistant, and iTunes. So...? :\ (My apologies, I'm really not a Mac user. This machine belongs to school.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you building at the command line, or in an application such as Eclipse or Netbeans? I'd check that you don't have multiple copies of Java installed, including an older 1.5 version that may not have SwingWorker.

Comment: I'm compiling from Eclipse. How do I check for multiple copies of Java?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Eclipse, but take a look [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for checking the JDK it is using.